# sqlite journal file location

Tags: php, apache, unix, sqlite, permissions

Curently sqlite is writing journal file in the same directory where is placed  database file. It makes a problem with the directory permission (it has to be writable).
Is there any method to force sqlite to write journal files in other directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use `PRAGMA journal_mode = PERSIST`.

Comment: well, it does not change permissions requirements

Comment: No, but if you create the journal file with an account that has rights to create a file on the directory (e.g. run VACUUM), the journal will be there and will not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the journal_mode to OFF or MEMORY should do the trick.

http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode